# What is creating this div height?

Tags: css

At [this page](http://freightplus.com/beta/example3.html), there is a testimonials box at top right.

[image]

Can you see what is creating the height of this box?

There is no height set for any element in the chain, and the sub elements are not as tall as the TD table cell.

Help appreciated.

Comment: what do you want  ??

Comment: can you show me the url of that site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using** `line-height: 1;` in your Class

```
 .cycle-slideshow  {
      line-height: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the unwanted space inside testimonial section is generating a `padding-bottom of 15px`. Try to remove that padding.

It should look like this:

```
.testimonial-box {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Or set a `line-height` to the `gs_testimonial_container`:

```
.gs_testimonial_container {
      line-height: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is creating height for table. As mentioned there table line-height is defined 2.

```
Line no. 226 : table {border-spacing: 0;line-height: 2;margin-bottom: 40px;width: 100%;word-break: break-word;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line height is set to 2. This is what creating the height for that box. Try changing it to 1, that will fix the issue.

```
line-height: 1;
```